# approaches for computing confidence band and prediction band for general regression analysis and predictive models

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, prediction-interval

In linear regression model, the `predict` in `R` is able to calculate the `confidence band` and `prediction band`. But for the general predictive models, what are the normal approaches to calculate `confidence band` and `prediction band`? I am asking this is because I am experimenting different models for a given data set. The users would like to get `confidence band` and `prediction band` as what `predict.lm` can give. However, not all those model packages provide these two bands-related information. I may have to write my algorithm to calculate them.

Comment: You are probably correct: You may have to implement this yourself. Your question is very broad.

Comment: What are the general approaches? Is that based on bootstrap?